# wamp - What is the 'root' user, and why does it appear under localhost and '127.0.0.1'?

Tags: mysql, localhost

I created a new db in WAMP, and I note that under the 'Privileges' tab that list the users I have one user that I didn't create, named 'root'.  What is it?  It is listed twice, once under 'localhost' and once under '127.0.0.1'.  I understand that this is the address for 'localhost', but why list it twice?  Also, I created a user, 'admin', and it appears under 'localhost', but not 127.0.0.1'.  I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, the `root` user is a system default.  What the users are "appearing under" is the host specification for the user; this allows controlling of the devices that a user is able to log in from.  Oftentimes this can be restricted to a single device (as in your case, since the web server is on the same system), but in other cases remote access is needed from different location/network or a number of locations; this would require different host specifications.

The system default `root` account is specified with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as a failsafe for when the `skip-name-resolve` option is used in the configuration; in that case, the `localhost` specification is useless and `root` would be unable to log in without the `127.0.0.1` entry.

Comment: +1 Very good and simple explaination.  I've always wondered why there was a localhost and 127.0.0.1 entry... :)